# Tidyverse install inside a RUN instruction is failing with "non zero exit status"

Tags: r, docker, installation, tidyverse

I'm using the command `RUN R -e "install.packages(c("tidyverse"), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"` inside Dockerfile to build a project, obtaining an empty build.
The error which I recieve during build is for R language:

> 1: In install.packages(c("tidyverse"), repos =
> "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
> #8 7.643   installation of package ‘systemfonts’ had non-zero exit status
>
> #8 7.643 2: In install.packages(c("tidyverse"), repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
> #8 7.643   installation of package ‘textshaping’ had non-zero exit status
>
> #8 7.643 3: In install.packages(c("tidyverse"), repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
> #8 7.643   installation of package ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status
>
> #8 7.643 4: In install.packages(c("tidyverse"), repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
> #8 7.643   installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
> #8 7.643 >

These packages are dependent on `tidyverse` and should be installed for proper built.

Comment: You should use `https`, not `http`, but I don't think that will cause an error.  It's likely a permissions issue.  Are you sure that process has write permission on the package library?

Comment: Your docker image is likely missing a system dependency. Is the output you are showing truncated? Normally you see a lot more information when installing packages and the exact error is usually included earlier in the output. What exactly does your build file look like?